# Control.Hide(); (WinForms) equivalent in Cocoa C# project

Tags: c#, xcode, cocoa, visual-studio-mac

Is there a control in Cocoa C # projects to hide interface objects? How to hide controls, interface objects in the Cocoa C # project on mac. Is there a way?

My problem concerns the .Hide () control; which hides interface objects (Buttons, Letters, etc.) exists in Windows Forms projects and there are no Cocoa projects in it. I would ask for help.There were such things in windows forms:

`Label.Hide();`

I tried to do it does not work, it says that the label object has no definition .Hide ();

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483369-hidden?language=objc

Comment: This not working. How to use this method? It does not work:

Comment: Connect_outlet.Hidden(); or this: Connect_outlet.Hidden; or: Connect_outlet.Hidden = true; or: Connect_outlet.Hidden = false; Only the last two do not work properly, but they do not cause the button to be hidden